# Установка зависимостей через composer в Yii2-проекте

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Получил в наследство проект, но там нет папки `vendor`, я так понимаю нужно обновить через `composer`, чтобы установились все зависимости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установить composer

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55d6ead61b29c7bdee5cccfb50076874187bd9f21f65d8991d46ec5cc90518f447387fb9f76ebae1fbbacf329e583e30') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Ну и запустить

```
php composer.phar install
```

p.s. В корне проэкта

Comment: я почти так и сделал, но компосер у меня был установлен, а запустил я из файла composer.json